# Rendering line by line with a different color

Tags: ios, core-graphics

How does one efficiently render a number of lines to screen, one at a time, each with a different colour?

I would like to render these lines on screen one at a time so the rendering is in real time.

How exactly can these renders be part of the same context so that cleanup can easily occur or e.g. saving the context as an image?